# Upper bound on all NP problems

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, proof, np

Why can all NP problems be solved in *O(2^(n^k))*, aka EXPTIME?

Where n^k is a polynomial function of input size n, and can depend on size of problem. 
(k >= 0)

Comment: You can enumerate the entire search space if you have exponential time. For SAT, this means you can try every possible combination of values to see if any of them satisfy.

Comment: In the future you might want to post purely theoretical questions like these on [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

A problem is in NP if you can take a solution candidate and check *in polynomial time* whether it's the correct solution or not. So the complexity of testing one solution is O(n^k).

Since the candidate can be tested O(n^k) time, it can't take more than O(n^k) space.

There are 2^(n^k) possible candidates, so going over each of time and testing them takes `O(2^(n^k) * n^k)` time.

I doubt this is equivalent to O(2^(n^k)), but it's still very much in EXPTIME.

In fact, it's in a subclass of EXPTIME called P-SPACE.

Comment: `2^(n^k) * n^k = 2^(n^k + k * log2(n))`, and there definitely exists an m such that `n^k + k*log2(n) < n^m` for sufficiently large n